# Перевести строку символов из hex в ascii

Tags: c, hex, ascii, scanf

На вход подаётся строка в hecx в виде непрерывной строки либо парами через пробел. Ввод должен закончиться кнопкой `энтер`

```
57 58 59 56
57585956
```

На выходе я должен получить

```
WXY
```

Символ `V` должен отсечься

**Вот мой код**:

```
// Online C compiler to run C 

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    printf("+++++++++++++");
    int i, j=1;
    char err;
    
while (j<4) {
    scanf("%X",&i);
    if (i<256){
        printf("---------\n");
        printf( "%c \n",i);
        printf("-------end%d\n", j) ;
        j++;
    }
    if(err == '\n') {
        break;
    }
}
    

while(j>1){
    printf("%c", i);
    j--;
}
return 0;}
```

Сейчас пока рассматриваю ситуацию когда ввод идёт с пробелами, т.е. идеальный случай.
По моей логике программа должна вывести первые три символа так как у меня три итерации цикла. На каждой итерации один символ! Но! Программа ввод запрашивает бесконечно она даже не выходит из первой итерации!

У меня есть работающий код, но он не мой.в какой-то степени я упростил чужой код до состояния написанного, что бы самому дойти до осознания как он работает постепенно его усложняя.

Сейчас в написанном есть пару лишних конструкций в сравнении с чужим кодом.

Прошу помочь разобраться. Если будут другие команды в коде прошу объяснить ибо на данный момент я знаю только то что написано!!

**Upd 1**
Теперь суть в том чтобы на сплошной последовательности программа завершала работу без вывода чего либо! + Цикл не должен ограничиваться тремя выводимыми символами

ниже мой код

```
while (1) {
    scanf("%2X",&i);
    printf("%c \n",i);
    if (getchar()!=' '){
        printf("-------end%d\n", j);
        break;
    }
}
```

При вводе `5758`
программа выдает от `W` что меня не устраивает

Comment: Upd 1 Теперь суть в том чтобы на сплошной последовательности программа завершала работу без вывода чего либо! + Цикл не должен ограничиваться тремя выводимыми символами

ниже мой код

while (1) {
    scanf("%2X",&i);
    printf("%c \n",i);
    if (getchar()!=' '){
        printf("-------end%d\n", j);
        break;
    }
}
При вводе 5758 программа выдает от W что меня не устраивает

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в цикле увеличивается `i`, а надо увеличивать `j`

```
while (j<4) 
{
    scanf("%X",&i);
    if (i<256){
        printf("---------\n");
        printf( "%c \n",i);
        printf("-------end%d\n", j) ;
        j++; // вот здесь нужно увеличивать j
    }
}
```

Если будете подавать на вход одной строкой `57585956`, то `scanf()` воспримет это как 1 число.
В цикле проверяется введенное значение только `if(i<256){`. А если будет введен 0? Или 1? и т.д. Нужно проверять на код букв, или хотя бы печатных символов алфавита.

```
while (j<4) 
{
    scanf("%X",&i);
    if( i>65 && i<256 )
    {
```

Comment: не заметил, поправил, но все равно не работает
я сейчас не рассматриваю критичные случаи! На ввод я сам подаю только корректные значения. на данном этапе пытаюсь понять как работает функция SCANF, потому что она выводит не так как я думал, не могу понять почему?

`вот вывод 
+++++++++++++56
---------
V
-------end1
57
---------
W
-------end3
WWWW%`
 теперь нет второй интеграции!!! XD

Comment: Работает. Если ввести `57 58 59 56` то выдает `W X Y`. Т.е. первые 3 символа считывает и выводит. То же самое, если вводить по 1 символу `57`, `58` и `59`.

Comment: `scanf("%X",&i);` вводит целое число, представленное в шестнадцатиричном формате. Если в консоли вводите строку `57 58 59 56`, она попадает в буфер ввода. При первом вызове `scanf()` считает из буфера  `57`, при втором вызове - `58`, при третьем вызове - `59`. Остаток строки останется в буфере ввода. Если введете `57585956`, то при первом вызове `scanf()` воспримет это как 1 число. Чтобы она интерпретировала по 2 символа на число, нужно написать `scanf("%2X",&i);`